# Open balls in metric spaces

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $$f(x,y)=\frac{|x_1-y_1|}{1+|x_1-y_1|}+\frac{|x_2-y_2|}{1+|x_2-y_2|}$$ and $$g(x,y)=\begin{cases}0 & x=y \\ 1& x\neq y\end{cases}$$

I have shown that these two functions are metric, so $(\mathbb{R}^2,f)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^2,g)$ are metric spaces.

Now I want to draw the balls $B_1(0,1):=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2: f(x,0)<1\}$ and $B_2(0,1):=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2: g(x,0)<1\}$.

We have that $f(x,0)<1\Rightarrow \frac{|x_1|}{1+|x_1|}+\frac{|x_2|}{1+|x_2|}<1$, right?

How do we continue? For $B_2$ we have that $g(x,0)<1\Rightarrow \begin{cases}0 & x=0 \\ 1& x\neq 1\end{cases}<1$. What do we get from that?

$$$$

EDIT:

The graph of $\frac{x}{1+x}+\frac{y}{1+y}<1$ with $x,y>0$ is the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, sketching $f(x,0) = 1$ might help. In order to do that, it might help to sketch ${x \over 1+x} + {y \over 1+y}$ for $x,y \geq 0$ first, and generalise. From here, a sketch of $B_1(0,1)$ should be much easier.

In the second case, it looks like you have an error in your last line - I'm not sure if this is a typo or a genuine mistake but double check it nonetheless. In this case, what does $x$ have to be to get $g(x,0) < 1$?

Comment: I added the graph of ${x \over 1+x} + {y \over 1+y}$ in my initial post. What do we get from that? I haven't really understood that. At $B_2(0,1)$ is only the point $x=0$, right?

Comment: Right! Now, can you think of what the graph ${|x| \over 1+|x|} + {|y| \over 1+|y|} \leq 1$ might look like?

Comment: For $B_2(0,1)$ - yes! Remember though that $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Isn't the graph of my post the graph of ${|x| \over 1+|x|} + {|y| \over 1+|y|} \leq 1$ ?

Comment: It is, for $x,y\geq0$, but I'm now talking about for general $x,y$.

Comment: Oh ok.Do we rotate the graph above to get the desired graph?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76040/discussion-between-b-mehta-and-mary-star).